# Online check in before the time allowed

Tags: airlines, check-in, lufthansa, sin

I will be flying on Lufthansa and the policy is check-in opens 23 hours prior to the flight. However, I went to familiarise myself with the procedure and found that I could access and do online check-in even though it's more than 23 hours prior to the flight.

I would like to know if the airline will still consider my check-in to be valid. Or would I have to do check-in again when the official period starts?

When I check in online it shows as “already checked in” and the boarding pass is available.

(No bags to check in just a carry on. It’s at Singapore’a Changi airport).

Comment: @HankyPanky I definitely wouldn't say useless, as in many situations you can pick your seat at that point, and the earlier you do it, the more choices you have. Not sure if that's indeed the case for Lufthansa.

Comment: And some airlines do only allow free check-in online and you have to pay (quite a bit compared to the cost of the ticket) when you want to check in at the airport. (Not Lufthansa.)

Comment: @HankyPanky also if the flight is full due to overbooking, earlier check-ins usually get priority over peers checked-in later.

Comment: And some airliners allow faster, or separate lines, for luggage check in if you registered it online

Comment: Online check-in with luggage isn't necessarily useless. Bagage drop counters, when they exist (and, unlike places like BOD, are not the only available option), can be much faster than manual check-in.

Comment: You may have gotten lucky there. In my experience  Lufthansa is pretty strict about the 23 hours rule. The FRA flight from BKK leaves around midnight, so it's possible that there was a time zone or date change hiccup. Anyway, once you have a boarding pass you are good to go

Comment: @hilmar yep hopefully. They asked for my email where the info would be sent & which I didn’t receive. However on the same page they opened up a file containing my boarding pass. To be safe I guess I will check again at the official valid time but looks good so far

Answer (score 18):

When you receive your boarding pass it is valid for sure.

There is no re-checkin to be done, you are good to go. Nothing else is required.

Comment: Seems plausible, but do you have a source to back that up? Is that indeed airline or general policy?

Comment: Every airline I've ever flown on would only let you check in as early as it was valid to do so.

Comment: That’s the thing @stannius it was possible to check in before it was even valid to do so in my case

Comment: Well, dates are hard for us programmers: http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/01/28/falsehoods-programmers-date-time-zones.html

Comment: @SQB which kind of source do you need to know that a boarding pass is actually a boarding pass?? if it wasn't a boarding pass it would have been written on it a different name.

Comment: @Val well, while I agree that it's very, _very_ likely valid, you're not providing any more information than the querant did. Based on that information, the querant asks, "is this valid?", to which you reply, "yeah, it's valid." To quote the Dude, "yeah, well, you know, that's just, like, your opinion, man."

Answer (score 3):

Wait until you're within the 23 hour window and try the checkin again. It'll probably say "you're already checked in!" and give you options to re-print (or re-mail) your boarding passes, and probably choose seat upgrades, extra baggage, and other extra-cost options. So you'll know your in.

If it seems to allow you to check in all over again, then something went wrong. Maybe they caught the error that allowed too-early checkin and invalidated them. In which case, do it again.